# Why isn't this tail-recursive?

Tags: recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I'm working through the book [Real-World Functional Programming](http://www.manning.com/petricek/), and I tried to come up with my own example of tail recursion before reading the book's example (listing 10.2, p. 265). The book's example works; mine causes a stack overflow.

I've found if I use a tuple argument or pre-calculate `a + accum` then mine will work. I want to understand why.

```
let rnd = new System.Random()
let test2 = List.init 1000000 (fun _ -> rnd.Next(-50, 51))

let rec sum2 list accum =
  match list with
  | [] -> accum
  | a::b -> sum2 b a + accum

let result = sum2 test2 0

printfn "%d" result
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sum2 b a + accum
```

Note that this is parsed as `(sum2 b a) + accum`, not `sum2 b (a + accum)`.

So this calls `sum2 b a`. Then it takes the result of that call and adds `accum` to it. So the last expression evaluated is the addition, not the call to `sum2`. Thus the call to `sum2` is not a tail call.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the compiler is reading

```
a::b -> (sum2 b a) + accum
```

instead of

```
a::b -> sum2 b (a + accum)
```

Comment: Aaargh! You and @sepp2k are spot-on. It's order of evaluation. The parentheses fix it.

Comment: I usually over-parenthesize everything, as I have found it is the lesser evil. Yay common lisp!!!